# How to enable Spark mesos docker executor?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, mesos

I'm working on integration between Mesos & Spark. For now, I can start SlaveMesosDispatcher in a docker; and I like to also run Spark executor in Mesos docker. I do the following configuration for it, but I got an error; any suggestion?

Configuration:

Spark: conf/spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.mesos.executor.docker.image        ubuntu
spark.mesos.executor.docker.volumes      /usr/bin:/usr/bin,/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib,/usr/lib:/usr/lib,/lib:/lib,/home/test/workshop/spark:/root/spark
spark.mesos.executor.home                /root/spark
#spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME             /root/spark
spark.executorEnv.MESOS_NATIVE_LIBRARY   /usr/local/lib
```

NOTE: The spark are installed in /home/test/workshop/spark, and all dependencies are installed.

After submit SparkPi to the dispatcher, the driver job is started but failed. The error messes is:

```
I1015 11:10:29.488456 18697 exec.cpp:134] Version: 0.26.0
I1015 11:10:29.506619 18699 exec.cpp:208] Executor registered on slave b7e24114-7585-40bc-879b-6a1188cb65b6-S1
WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities, memory limited without swap.
/bin/sh: 1: ./bin/spark-submit: not found
```

Does any know how to map/set spark home in docker for this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue you're seeing here is a result of the current working directory of the container isn't where Spark is installed. When you specify a docker image for Spark to use with Mesos, it expects the default working directory of the container to be inside `$SPARK_HOME` where it can find ./bin/spark-submit.

[You can see that logic here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/mesos/MesosClusterScheduler.scala#L381-L385).

It doesn't look like you're able to configure the working directory through Spark configuration itself, which means you'll need to build a custom image on top of `ubuntu` that simply does a `WORKDIR /root/spark`.

Comment: I have seen the same issue running Spark on Mesos and Docker. In my case it was easier to adjust the path to my local spark-shell / spark-submit using a symbolic link and run it from there, since I did not want to change the path in the docker image.

Comment: @tarnfeld I build the docker image from 'FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk' and change the current working directory to spark home but still get ./bin/spark-submit: not found